# Why do I get 6 entries in an array created from a map with only 3 entities?

Tags: go

I have a seemingly simple issue with my understanding of map types in Go. If I create a simple map such as

```
var thisMap = map[string]string {
  "8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543": "Charming",
  "1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc": "Citi",
  "e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5": "Chase",
}
```

Populate the keys into an array

```
keys := make([]string, len(supportedCards))
for k := range supportedCards {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
```

Then try to join these keys into a comma separated value that I can append to any string

```
fmt.Println(strings.Join(keys,","))
```

I expect the result to be

```
8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543,1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc,e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5
```

But what I really see is

```
,,,8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543,1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc,e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5
```

Why does iterating through the map create 6 entries instead of just 3?

https://play.golang.org/p/Ou67K1Kfvsf

Comment: duh...go ahead and slam me...i am initializing the array with a length of 3 then appending...

Comment: You're working with a slice, not an array.

Comment: Is it only my impression that questions about go are much more often downvoted than questions from other categories (-2 at the time of writing this comment)? This one is perfectly valid for me. Upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
keys := make([]string, len(supportedCards))
```

you create a `[]string` with three empty elements. You can assign them using their indicies.

When you append it later, new entries are added at the end, producing your result with a length of 6, where the first three are empty.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @xarantolus's answer, instead of using indices you can keep your for-range loop unchanged by:

```golang
keys := make([]string, 0, len(supportedCards))
```

The third argument is capacity of the slide. Ref: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13